# How is the Preview class connected/linked to the Activity Class for the PhotoIntentActivity example?

Tags: android, sdk

I am a beginner into Android-SDK Development. I downloaded the PhotoIntentActivity sample from this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html) and attempted to modify it. I tried to understand the working of the Preview Class by using Log.d() debugging statements within the functions SurfaceChanged(), SurfaceDestroyed(), etc. However, it did not give anything in the LogCat, by which I am compelled to interpret, that the Activity class does not communicate with the Preview Class. Am I doing anything wrong, do I have any remnant coding to fill it with? I would be obliged if you could furnish any resources from which I can get some exhaustive learning. Thanks.

This is the PhotoIntentActivity code:

```
    package com.example.android.photobyintent;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.VideoView;



public class PhotoIntentActivity extends Activity {

private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B = 1;
private static final int ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_S = 2;
private static final int ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO = 3;

private Preview mPreview;
Camera mCamera;
int numberOfCameras;
int cameraCurrentlyLocked;
int defaultCameraId;

private static final String BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY = "viewbitmap";
private static final String IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "imageviewvisibility";
private ImageView mImageView;
private Bitmap mImageBitmap;

private static final String VIDEO_STORAGE_KEY = "viewvideo";
private static final String VIDEOVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY = "videoviewvisibility";
private VideoView mVideoView;
private Uri mVideoUri;

private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_";
private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";

private AlbumStorageDirFactory mAlbumStorageDirFactory = null;


/* Photo album for this application */
private String getAlbumName() {
    return getString(R.string.album_name);
}


private File getAlbumDir() {
    File storageDir = null;

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {

        storageDir = mAlbumStorageDirFactory.getAlbumStorageDir(getAlbumName());

        if (storageDir != null) {
            if (! storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                if (! storageDir.exists()){
                    Log.d("CameraSample", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), "External storage is not mounted READ/WRITE.");
    }

    return storageDir;
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
    File albumF = getAlbumDir();
    File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, albumF);
    return imageF;
}

private File setUpPhotoFile() throws IOException {

    File f = createImageFile();
    mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();

    return f;
}

private void setPic() {

    /* There isn't enough memory to open up more than a couple camera photos */
    /* So pre-scale the target bitmap into which the file is decoded */

    /* Get the size of the ImageView */
    int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
    int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

    /* Get the size of the image */
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    /* Figure out which way needs to be reduced less */
    int scaleFactor = 1;
    if ((targetW > 0) || (targetH > 0)) {
        scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH); 
    }

    /* Set bitmap options to scale the image decode target */
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    /* Decode the JPEG file into a Bitmap */
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);

    /* Associate the Bitmap to the ImageView */
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    mVideoUri = null;
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE");
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int actionCode) {

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    switch(actionCode) {
    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B:
        File f = null;

        try {
            f = setUpPhotoFile();
            mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            f = null;
            mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;          
    } // switch

    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);
}

private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
}

private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    mImageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
    mVideoUri = null;
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void handleBigCameraPhoto() {

    if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
        setPic();
        galleryAddPic();
        mCurrentPhotoPath = null;
    }

}

private void handleCameraVideo(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("PIC", "Entering PIC");
    mVideoUri = intent.getData();
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(mVideoUri);
    mImageBitmap = null;
    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
    boolean qOpened = false;

    try {
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        mCamera = Camera.open(id);
        qOpened = (mCamera != null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return qOpened;    
}

private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {

    mPreview.setCamera(null);
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

Button.OnClickListener mTakePicOnClickListener = 
    new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B);
    }
};

Button.OnClickListener mTakePicSOnClickListener = 
    new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dispatchTakePictureIntent(ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_S);
    }
};

Button.OnClickListener mTakeVidOnClickListener = 
    new Button.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dispatchTakeVideoIntent();
    }
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    mImageBitmap = null;
    mVideoUri = null;

    Button picBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIntend);
    setBtnListenerOrDisable( 
            picBtn, 
            mTakePicOnClickListener,
            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
    );
/*
    Button picSBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIntendS);
    setBtnListenerOrDisable( 
            picSBtn, 
            mTakePicSOnClickListener,
            MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
    );
*/
    Button vidBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIntendV);
    setBtnListenerOrDisable( 
            vidBtn, 
            mTakeVidOnClickListener,
            MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE
    );

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new FroyoAlbumDirFactory();
    } else {
        mAlbumStorageDirFactory = new BaseAlbumDirFactory();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            handleBigCameraPhoto();
        }
        break;
    } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_B

    case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_S: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            handleSmallCameraPhoto(data);
        }
        break;
    } // ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_S

    case ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            handleCameraVideo(data);
        }
        break;
    } // ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO
    } // switch
}

// Some lifecycle callbacks so that the image can survive orientation change
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY, mImageBitmap);
    outState.putParcelable(VIDEO_STORAGE_KEY, mVideoUri);
    outState.putBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mImageBitmap != null) );
    outState.putBoolean(VIDEOVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY, (mVideoUri != null) );
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mImageBitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(BITMAP_STORAGE_KEY);
    mVideoUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(VIDEO_STORAGE_KEY);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(mImageBitmap);
    mImageView.setVisibility(
            savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IMAGEVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ? 
                    ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
    );
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(mVideoUri);
    mVideoView.setVisibility(
            savedInstanceState.getBoolean(VIDEOVIEW_VISIBILITY_STORAGE_KEY) ? 
                    ImageView.VISIBLE : ImageView.INVISIBLE
    );
}

/**
 * Indicates whether the specified action can be used as an intent. This
 * method queries the package manager for installed packages that can
 * respond to an intent with the specified action. If no suitable package is
 * found, this method returns false.
 * http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/can-i-use-this-intent.html
 *
 * @param context The application's environment.
 * @param action The Intent action to check for availability.
 *
 * @return True if an Intent with the specified action can be sent and
 *         responded to, false otherwise.
 */
public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, String action) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    List<ResolveInfo> list =
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}

private void setBtnListenerOrDisable( 
        Button btn, 
        Button.OnClickListener onClickListener,
        String intentName
) {
    if (isIntentAvailable(this, intentName)) {
        btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);            
    } else {
        btn.setText( 
            getText(R.string.cannot).toString() + " " + btn.getText());
        btn.setClickable(false);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could we see your code?

Comment: Have uploaded the Activity code.